# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Void

Tags: flash

I am trying to create a jigsaw puzzle with Flash professional but have been getting this error. I dont know anything about Flash Coding. Please assist me to get it done.

All i know is this with this coding i can move a piece with cursor.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);
function EntFrame(e:Event):Void {

    //piece1
    Piece1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,DragP1);
    function DragP1(event:MouseEvent):void {
        Piece1.startDrag();
    }

    Stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,DropP1);
    function DropP1(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Piece.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change "Void" to "void".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have drag and drop in an enter_frame event. Here is example code. The example code uses "mcPiece" for the instance name of the movieclip (better naming convention).

You add the mouse event listeners to the movieclip. "this" in the functions refers to the target of the the mouse event - whatever movieclip the mouse event is assigned to - in this case it's mcPiece. This way you can use the same function for any movieclip you assign the event to.

```
mcPiece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fDragMC);
mcPiece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fDropMC);

function fDragMC(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.startDrag();
}

function fDropMC(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this.stopDrag();
}
```